I have a Blazor Server app which is not working properly after published in IIS but works on localhost
I have a Blazor Server app which is running fine on localhost. I published the app to IIS on a remote server; it works fine, even in localhost on the remote server, but the UI and other functionality is not working properly and rendering in published URL of the app.
I like to know what causes this issue

More information is needed. When you say it is not working, what exactly is happening? For example, if you click a button, does it not work?

First make sure that the ASP.NET Core module is enabled and the app has sufficient permissions in IIS. Then view the IIS logs for more error messages and see if there are any error messages related to Blazor Server app in the console.
